# PHP gera erro 403 em parte do código

Tags: php, http-status-code-403

Tenho uma página PHP para cadastro de dados (utilizando uma página com vários formulários), quando vou cadastrar o item "Categoria" (que registra o dado em MySQL) funciona perfeito, porém quando vou cadastrar uma empresa dá o erro 403.

Isso acontece no mesmo arquivo (eu faço o processo sem usar outro arquivo) e ambos os formulários apenas cadastram os dados no MySQL. Já tentei alterar e excluir o .htaccess mas não deu certo.

Estava tudo funcionando e cheguei a cadastrar várias categorias e empresas e do nada ele começou com este erro.

Comment: Procure nos logs do servidor (apache, nginx, etc) e também ative todos os logs de erro do php.

Comment: Apresente os códigos. Pode haver algo que passou despercebido

Comment: Isso pode ser alguma regra de segurança. Se você utiliza o `mod_security` (ou afins) ele pode bloquear requisições "suspeitas", apresentando o `403`.